cvlc does not work on Ubuntu server 24.04
I have Ubuntu server 24.04 installed on a mini pc with a J4125 cpu. I want to run cvlc to display an rtsp stream on the monitor attached to the hdmi port from the command line.
When I run cvlc rtsp://10.10.1.25:8554/cam101 I get the following error messages:
VLC media player 3.0.20 Vetinari (revision 3.0.20-0-g6f0d0ab126b)
[00005bacd4007d10] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[00005bacd3f23550] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[00005bacd4007d10] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[00007d593c001580] satip stream error: Failed to setup RTSP session
[00007d5944000c90] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[00007d5944000c90] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://10.10.1.25:8554/cam101'. Check the log for details.```

I have confirmed that this rtsp stream is available because I can
display it from this mini pc using ```ffplay```. I have searched
online for help but haven't seen anything. I am hoping someone here
can help me. I get the same errors when I try running ```clvc``` on a
mini pc with an N5105 cpu running Ubuntu server 24.04.

Any suggestions?

Here's an excerpt from the log:

```[00005a3881a30b60] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "dbus,none": 19 candidates
[00005a3881a30b60] dbus interface debug: listening on dbus as: org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc
[00005a3881a30b60] main interface debug: using interface module "dbus"
[00005a3881a34ea0] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "hotkeys,none": 19 candidates
[00005a3881a34ea0] main interface debug: using interface module "hotkeys"
[00005a3881a358e0] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "globalhotkeys,none": 19 candidates
[00005a3881a358e0] main interface debug: no interface modules matched
[00005a3881a358e0] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[00005a3881952550] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[00005a3881a358e0] main interface debug: looking for interface module matching "dummy": 19 candidates
[00005a3881a358e0] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[00005a3881a358e0] main interface debug: using interface module "dummy"
[00005a38819ea2a0] main playlist debug: processing request item: null, node: Playlist, skip: 0
[00005a38819ea2a0] main playlist debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
[00005a38819ea2a0] main playlist debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index -1
[00005a38819ea2a0] main playlist debug: starting playback of new item
[00005a38819ea2a0] main playlist debug: resyncing on rtsp://10.10.1.25:8554/cam101
[00005a38819ea2a0] main playlist debug: rtsp://10.10.1.25:8554/cam101 is at 0
[00005a38819ea2a0] main playlist debug: creating new input thread
[00007c5220000c90] main input debug: Creating an input for 'rtsp://10.10.1.25:8554/cam101'
[00005a38819ea2a0] main playlist debug: requesting art for new input thread
[00007c5220000c90] main input debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB
[00007c5220000c90] main input debug: using default timeshift path
[00007c5220000c90] main input debug: `rtsp://10.10.1.25:8554/cam101' gives access `rtsp' demux `any' path `10.10.1.25:8554/cam101'
[00007c5218000fb0] main input source debug: creating demux: access='rtsp' demux='any' location='10.10.1.25:8554/cam101' file='(null)'
[00007c5218001140] main demux debug: looking for access_demux module matching "rtsp": 18 candidates
[00007c5218001140] main demux debug: no access_demux modules matched
[00007c5218001580] main stream debug: creating access: rtsp://10.10.1.25:8554/cam101
[00007c5218001580] main stream debug: looking for access module matching "rtsp": 30 candidates
[00007c5218001580] satip stream debug: try to open 'rtsp://10.10.1.25:8554/cam101'
[00007c5218001580] satip stream debug: connect to host '10.10.1.25'
[00007c5218001580] main stream debug: net: connecting to 10.10.1.25 port 8554
[00007c520c000c30] main meta fetcher debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates

...

[00007c520c000c30] main art finder debug: no art finder modules matched
[00007c5218001580] main stream debug: connection succeeded (socket = 11)
[00007c5218001580] main stream debug: net: opening 0.0.0.0 datagram port 9130
[00007c5218001580] main stream debug: net: opening 0.0.0.0 datagram port 9131
[00007c5218001580] satip stream error: Failed to setup RTSP session
[00007c5218001580] main stream debug: net: connecting to 10.10.1.25 port 8554
[00007c5218001580] main stream debug: connection succeeded (socket = 11)
[00007c5218001580] access_realrtsp stream warning: Cseq mismatch, got 1, assumed 0
[00007c5218001580] access_realrtsp stream debug: rtsp connected
[00007c5218001580] access_realrtsp stream warning: only real/helix rtsp servers supported for now
[00007c5218001580] main stream debug: no access modules matched
[00007c5220000c90] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[00007c5220000c90] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://10.10.1.25:8554/cam101'. Check the log for details.
[00005a38819ea2a0] main playlist debug: dead input
[00005a38819ea2a0] main playlist debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
[00005a38819ea2a0] main playlist debug: nothing to play```


What does the log say?   Also, is X installed?  Can you play regular videos?  Also, looking at the output line "satip stream error: Failed to setup RTSP session" - I wonder if the version of vlc you are using does not have support for rtsp built in.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360613/unable-to-play-any-rtsp-streams-in-xubuntu-and-debian

It would seem your answer is in the log - access_realrtsp stream warning: only real/helix rtsp servers supported for now - Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469388/upgraded-to-22-04-2-lts-now-vlc-cant-open-rtsp-stream
